# How to compute Nash equilibria for this 3x3 matrix

Tags: nash-equilibrium

\begin{matrix}
&P2 \\
P1&0,0 & 7,6 & 6,7 \\
&6,7 & 0,0 & 7,6 \\
&7,6 & 6,7 & 0,0
 \end{matrix}

Then:

For P1:
\begin{matrix}
 & A &B&C \\
  A&0,0 & \underline{7},6 & 6,7 \\
  B&6,7 & 0,0 & \underline{7},6 \\
  C&\underline{7},6 & 6,7 & 0,0
 \end{matrix}

For P2:
\begin{matrix}
 & A &B&C \\
  A&0,0 & 7,6 & 6,\underline{7} \\
  B&6,\underline{7} & 0,0 & 7,6 \\
  C&7,6 & 6,\underline{7} & 0,0
 \end{matrix}

Now merge:
\begin{matrix}
 & A &B&C \\
  A&0,0 & \underline{7},6 & 6,\underline{7} \\
  B&6,\underline{7} & 0,0 & \underline{7},6 \\
  C&\underline{7},6 & 6,\underline{7} & 0,0
 \end{matrix}

And now what?
I need to select the cell that both values are selected but there is no cell like that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I edited the table. Hope it is ok now.

Comment: It doesn't seem there is a pure equilibrium. You might need to consider mixed strategies.

Comment: And the equilibrium mixed strategy seems fairly obvious from the rotational symmetry

Comment: I cant get it..

Comment: Just to be sure, row B column A is really supposed to be $0,7,$ and not $6,7?$ $6,7$ would make the question slightly easier.

Comment: @henry There isn't a rotational symmetry - there is row B, column A, which is at odds. That was why I wondered if there was an error in copying the matrix.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You have eagle eyes. It is $6,7$ in the top table

Comment: yes it is 6,7. I will edit it now. sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this as a Rock/Paper/Scissors sort of game, where a match is a tie, with no payoff for either player, but when not a tie, the winner gets $7$ points and the loser get $6.$

As with Rock Paper Scissors, it helps not in the least for a player to prefer one option over the other. So the best option is for each player to pick each option with equal probability, which is indeed a Nash equilibrium.

Showing there is no other Nash equilibrium might be a little work, but (1) not much work, and (2) you didn't ask for all.